# How to Import Excel/Spreadsheet into an existing Sharepoint List using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like import some data of an excel sheet to existing list. I see that this can be done using power shell or by using C#.

Can somebody help me in doing this using JavaScript by adding a web part. to have a button which by clicking should allow us to upload excel sheet when we chose the right sheet it should take those necessary columns from the sheet and add to the list if any thing changed to the old ones then it shall be updated.

Kindly someone help me in finding a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use JavaScript API for Office

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160953.aspx

Then read excel file and then use JavaScript SharePoint Object Model to push changes to Custom List.